# javascript regex test() fails when regex in variable during jasmine test

Tags: javascript, regex, jasmine

I'm trying to do a simple js regex pattern match against a string during a jasmine test. This line works as expected:

```
(/[^0-9\.]/g).test('$'); // true
```

However, when the regex is stored in a variable, it breaks:

```
var NON_CURRENCY_VALUES = /[^0-9\.]/g; 
NON_CURRENCY_VALUES.test('$'); // false
```

Both return `true`, as expected, when run from the console. However, when run from inside the jasmine test, it breaks.

see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Lyhsq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`test` has weird and unhelpful behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

> test called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match.

You can get around this by [setting `RegExp.lastIndex = 0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) before each match is attempted, but be wary of this behavior.

http://plnkr.co/edit/cne6He?p=preview

Comment: thanks! out of curiosity, why should I be wary of this behavior?

Comment: @ChrisMontgomery I meant the default `.test` behavior.  It's already bitten you once, so you can see why you should be wary.  `.exec` does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

`NON_CURRENCY_VALUES.test('$');` is returning true for me.

However to store a regex in a variable you can also use RegExp:

```
var NON_CURRENCY_VALUES = new RegExp("[^0-9\.]", "g");
```

Comment: No its not private, just click on `Run` (jsfiddle has some issues today)

Comment: ah, got it running now. So ya, like I mentioned in my question, it works fine if run directly once. Where I'm having issues is inside my js test where I run the same test multiple times in a row.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Thanks, I know about that behavior of `test` method. It wasn't clear from OP's example code above that same regex is calling it multiple times. I guess that's indeed the reason here.